# No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python

I want to import BeautifulSoup. But there is a problem. The BeautifulSoup library has installed in anaconda.

```
C:\Users\q>pip install BeautifulSoup4
Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup4 in c:\users\q\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

But when i want to import BeautifulSoup, it trigger an error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Here is result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  

File "C:\Users\q\pyfile\ipsearch.py", line 1, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Why? The reason is to the path of python's site-packages and the path to anaconda's site-packages trigger a confilct? A month ago, i use it successfully, at that time, my computer has installed python3.5 and anaconda. But now, it trigger an error. Why? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: use pip3 and install

Comment: Thanks, i install it successfully.

Comment: As @bigbounty suggested, you might already have BeautifulSoup installed for Python 2, but not Python 3.

Comment: @Galen I haven't install Python2, so i think when i install library i don't need to use pip3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following command:

```
pip install --ignore-installed beautifulsoup4
```